# Getting and setting the bytecode counter in Python

Tags: python, bytecode

Various bytecode instructions in Python like `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` take a target to jump to. Is there bytecode instruction(s) to jump to the TOS (top of stack)? What about pushing the current position (bytecode counter) to the TOS?

This would allow interruptions and resuming (yes, I know this can be simulated with function calls or yield but that isn't the question here).

I'm using [cpyasm](https://github.com/abarnert/cpyasm) to generate bytecode although that may not be important to this question.

A positive answer for any version of Python 2.x or 3.x would be helpful. If its not possible, can I create a Python module in C to add this feature? Or is the only way to modify the CPython source?

Comment: What do you even mean by "jump to the top of stack"? The top of the stack isn't an instruction, so jumping there makes no sense. Are you trying to read jump targets from integers on the stack?

Comment: Essentially, yes. Integers would work if that's the format. Maybe I should reverse the two questions. Get the current position on the TOS and (later) jump to it.